# Easiest way to edit a huge geoJSON?

Tags: javascript, geojson, qgis

I'm sitting here with a huge geoJSON that I got from an Open Street Map shape-file. However, most of the polygons are unnecessary. These could, in theory, easily be singled out based on certain properties.

But how do I query the geoJSON file to remove certain elements (features)? Or would it be easier to save the shape-file in another format (working in QGIS)?

Link to sample of json-file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15955488/hki_test_sample.json (240 kB)

Comment: Can you give us the JSON also, or tell us where to get it at?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "query the geoJSON," are you talking about having the source where you get the geoJSON give you a subset of data?  There is no widely-implemented standard for "querying" JSON like this, but each site you retrieve from may have its own parameters to reduce the size of data you get.

If you're talking about paring down the data in client-side code, simply looping through the structure and removing properties (with `delete`) and array items is what you'd have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Shapefile beats GeoJSON for large (not mega) data. It supports random access to features. To get at the GeoJSON features in a collection you have to read and deserialize the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to edit it and what software is available you have a few options. If you have access to Safe FME this is by far the best geographic feature manipuluation software and will give you tons of options (it can read / write (and convert between) just about any geographic format). If you're just looking for a text editor that can handle the volume of data I would look at Notepad++ - it can hold a lot of text and you can do find / replace using regular expressions. Safe FME can be a little pricy, but you might be able to get a trial

Answer (score 0):

As Jacob says, just iterate and remove the elements you don't want. I like http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#reject for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to permanently remove fields just convert it to a shapefile, remove the fields you don't want, and re-export it as GeoJSON.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, but if anyone comes across this now, I'd recommend TopoJSON.

**Convert it to TopoJSON.**
By default TopoJSON removes all attributes, but you can flag those you'd like to keep like this:

```
topojson -o output.topojson -p fieldToKeep,anotherFieldToKeep input.geojson
```

More info in the [TopoJSON command line reference](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference)